# UILongPressGestureRecognizer of Superview gets called instead of Subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

i got a strange problem. I got a Superview with customcontrols as subviews.
Their are GestureRecognizer both in superview and subviews.
If i tap a subview its GestureRecognizer gets called and on tap on the superview its tap gets called.
but on long press in the subview SOMETIMES the GestureRecognizer of the superview gets called. I add the GestureRecognizers in the same functions but there is a different attitude.
**Superview**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapPiece:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
//contenView is the area where my controls can be
[self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTapGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTapPiece:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:longTapGesture];
[longTapGesture release];
```

**Subviews**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectPiece:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPiece:)];
longPressGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
```

Can anyone tell me why the longtap doen't response to my subview and how to fix it.
THANK YOU

Comment: got a solution but this is not what i wanted i set the duration of the control lower than the one of the superview
`[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:0.4];` But the gestureRecognizer should be independend

Comment: hello I met the same problem with you.  pls see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756615/uiimageview-cant-detect-long-press-gesture-in-a-customized-swippable-uitablevie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got a solution but this is not what i wanted i set the duration of the control lower than the one of the superview `[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:0.4];` But the gestureRecognizer should be independend