# UIImageView can't detect long press gesture in a customized swippable UITableViewCell which is a scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using the swippable `UITableViewCell` subclass as linked below:

https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

In my cell, there's a `UIImageView`.  I added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView`.  I want to make a 'Wiggle-Jiggle' effect when the `UIImageView` was long pressed.  But every time I long pressed the `UIImageView`, the whole cell was selected.  So I dived into the swippable `UITableViewCell` code.  I found that the cell itself was also set a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` as following:

```
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer = [[SWLongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewPressed:)];
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = kLongPressMinimumDuration;
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.cellScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

The code is from `SWTableViewCell.m` which you can find from the above link.

Now I want to know is there a way to lock the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the cell and trigger the action for the `UIImageView` when the `UIImageView` was long pressed?

Many thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason.  I posted it here just incase anybody else meet the same confusion in the future.

I the library I used, there is several lines code to set the `longPressGestureRecognizer`.

```
self.longPressGestureRecognizer = [[SWLongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewPressed:)];
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = kLongPressMinimumDuration;
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.cellScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

There's one line: `self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = kLongPressMinimumDuration;`  and the `#define kLongPressMinimumDuration 0.16f`.  So the reason of my issue is the duration **0.16f** is too small.  It'll be triggered earlier than my long press.  If I change the duration, like change it to 0.5s, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do next (think not the best solution, but you can try it)

Create custom cell for your tableView, add UIView as content holder. Than in cell.m file do next

1. register your gestrude

   ```
   - (void)initGestrudeRecognizer{
       UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGestrudeRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
       [self addGestureRecognizer:longGestrudeRecognizer];
   }
   ```

2.implement `longPress` action.In this method also all you need animation (you can easily modify it - below just as example)

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"long press gestrude recognized");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 animations:^{
        self.uiview.frame = CGRectMake(-20, 0, self.uiview.frame.size.width, self.uiview.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 animations:^{
                self.uiview.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, self.uiview.frame.size.width, self.uiview.frame.size.height);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished){
               self.uiview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.uiview.frame.size.width, self.uiview.frame.size.height);
            }];
        }];
    }
```

3. If you need to recognize more than one gestrude you need to implement `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` protocol and add method that simple return YES

   ```
   - (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
       return YES;
   }
   ```

If you dont want that your cell become selectable - simple choose selection type of cell to NONE

[image]

As result I got something like thin (on longPress)

[image]

Also good article about swipeGestrude usage you can find [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views). It's was very helpfull for me.

Comment: Thank you Kirill.  I'm just doing like you suggested.  Without the linked swippable talbeviewcell, my code works fine.  So i think to solve this problem, need to read the linked code.